# JavaFX/CSS: "-fx-background-radius: 10;" screws my background

Tags: java, css, javafx, background

I am dynamically creating some VBoxes in my game to show a smaller version of a card. For this I set the VBoxes a background (Object Background).

When trying to style them in CSS it actually works properly but when trying to round the corners with "-fx-background-radius: 10;" it actually does not show the background anymore.

I think it has something to do with how I create the background:

```
public Background getBackground(Boolean isOwnCard, Card card) {
    String fileName = card.getCardType().toString();
    BackgroundSize bgs;

    if (isOwnCard) {
        bgs = new BackgroundSize(110, 50, false, false, false, false);
    } else {
        bgs = new BackgroundSize(75, 50, false, false, false, false);
    }

    BackgroundImage bgi = new BackgroundImage(new Image("file:client.Resources/Images/CardImageSmall/" + fileName + ".jpg"), BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, bgs);
    Background bg = new Background(bgi);
    return bg;
}
```

With `-fx-background-radius: 10;` in CSS:

[image: Image of without the "-fx-background-radius: 10;" in CSS]

Without `-fx-background-radius` in CSS:

[image: Image with the background radius in CSS the background]

Is there any possibility to round the corners of the background? Did anyone have the same problem?

**EDIT**

I have tried it with setting the background in CSS but sadly the background still does not want to get rounded corners:

```css
#CardImageSmallBrown{
    -fx-background-image: url('../../client.Resources/Images/CardImageSmall/BRAUN.jpg"');
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), 10, 0, 0, 0);
    -fx-background-radius: 50px;
    -fx-border-radius: 50px;
    -fx-border-width: 5px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}
```

Result:

[image: image of result with CSS]

How do I round the edges of the background!?

Comment: Setting properties from CSS (i.e. an "author stylesheet" or "inline") take precedence over setting properties programmatically (i.e. `setProperty(...)`). My guess is, setting the background radius in CSS causes it to loose the other background information set in code. Try setting the background either all via CSS or all via code.

Comment: Thank you Slaw! I have tried it now with CSS but still don't get the result. You can see in the EDIT what I have changed. Do you know how to round the edge with css?

Comment: I was mistaken. I think the problem is `BackgroundImage` can't have corner radii. You may be able to work around this by setting the [`shape`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#shapeProperty) on your `Region`.

Comment: Alternatively set the `clip` property...